# Aligning loader to center of page and adding text to it

Tags: html, css

I have loader designed and I  positioned it to center with `top:0` `left:0` `z:10` and `text-align:center`. Its not positioning to center of the page. I also added a text called Loading But its's not showing up.

```css
#container-sleftpinner {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #666666;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .80;
}

.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  background: grey;
  -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  width: 1em;
  height: 4em;
}

.loader {
  color: grey;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  margin: 88px auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}

.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
}

.loader:before {
  left: -1.5em;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.loader:after {
  left: 1.5em;
}

.loader p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: -5em;
}

@-webkit-keyframes load1 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0;
    height: 4em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 -2em;
    height: 5em;
  }
}

@keyframes load1 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0;
    height: 4em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 -2em;
    height: 5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container-spinner" style="display:block;">
  <div class="loader">
    <p>Loading...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon your code.

give the `.container-spinner` class the following and the content will center.
I changed the display to be `flex` and made sure to give it  `hight:100vh` to fill the page and all that left is to center it vertically and horizontally using `justify-content` and `align-items` ( don't forget to remove the inline style to get this to work)

```
    .container-spinner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

[image: result]

### Edit

based upon your request. Here is the working code with the text showing up and all the changes to the HTML and CSS.

[image]

```css
.container-spinner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container-sleftpinner {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #666666;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  background: grey;
  -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  width: 1em;
  height: 4em;
}

.loader {
  color: grey;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}

.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
}

.loader:before {
  left: -1.5em;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.loader:after {
  left: 1.5em;
}

.container-spinner p {
  text-align: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes load1 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0;
    height: 4em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 -2em;
    height: 5em;
  }
}

@keyframes load1 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0;
    height: 4em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 -2em;
    height: 5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-spinner">
  <div class="loader">
  </div>
  <p>Loading...</p>
</div>
```

If that doesn't work please let me know.

Comment: Why the text is not displaying?

Comment: OH, I will check it out just a moment.

Comment: I fixed that and I added the changes in a snippet.